# Getting 404 error message on localhost while calling for jsp file created in spring mvc project

Tags: java, spring

I am getting an 404 error message on localhost while calling for jsp file created in spring mvc project

I have created dynamic web project in eclipse and added spring jars in it.
created controller and calling jsp file through it but getting 404 error msg. Server u

web.xml:

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  FirstMVCProject

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Post the URL you are hitting

Comment: Add controller, applicationContext and jsp

Answer (score 0):

You didn't load the context in the `web.xml` :

```
<init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
 </init-param>
```

**The proper web.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>example</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```